# Can't get original value after sending by serial port

Tags: c++, arduino, c++14

I have written a simple code for sending int value using bluetooth serial port.

Transmitter:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "PWM.hpp"

PWM PWM(2);
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(8,9);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);   
  Serial.println("Go");
  BTSerial.begin(9600);  
  BTSerial.write("AT+INQ\r\n");
  delay(10000); 
  BTSerial.write("AT+CONN1\r\n");
  delay(100);
  PWM.begin(true);
}

void loop()
{
  int pwmValue = PWM.getValue();
  Serial.println(pwmValue);
  BTSerial.write(pwmValue); 
  delay(100);
}
```

Output of `Serial.println` of transmitter part is correct:

```
1500
```

but on receiver part isn't. This is the code of receiver:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial BTSerial(8, 9);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BTSerial.begin(9600);
  BTSerial.write("AT+NAME=Remote\r\n");
}

void loop() {

 if (BTSerial.available()) {
  int pwmValue = BTSerial.read();
  Serial.println(pwmValue);
 }
```

Incorrect output of `Serial.println` is:

```
220
```

I think the issue is in typecasting.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If you have the answer, please write it in the _answer section_, not here. Thanks.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I have fixeed it but value is still wrong. Instead of `⸮⸮` there is now `220` but is wrong. Correct value is `1500`

Answer (score 2):

[`SoftwareSerial::read`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialRead) is returning a single byte read.
If you examine the expected `1500` in hexadecimal it is `0x05DC`, and it's lower byte is `0xDC` which is exactly `220` in decimal.

Comment: How can I get all bytes?

Comment: I think `SoftwareSerial` can only read one byte at a time. So loop.

Answer (score 1):

With the multi-byte variant of `write()` you could use:

```
BTSerial.write(&pwmValue, sizeof pwmValue);
```

For receiving you need a loop:

```
union {
    int  i;
    char c[0];
} pwmValue;
int receivedBytes = 0;

void loop() {
    if (BTSerial.available()) {
        pwmValue.c[receivedBytes] = BTSerial.read();
        receivedBytes++;
        if (receivedBytes == sizeof pwmValue) {
            Serial.println(pwmValue.i);
            receivedBytes = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I was misled by `Serial.read()` that has this overloaded variant. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In documentation https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/SoftwareSerial/blob/master/SoftwareSerial.cpp, you can see that both functions work with uint_8t -- which is guaranteed to have 8 bits (1 byte). That holds up to 256 of value, so **1500 mod 256 is 220**.

Looks like the library is prepared to transmit only char-sized data, so you need to convert bigger numbers on both size.

For sending int:

```
int n = pwmValue;

while (n > 0) {
    int digit = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
    BTSerial.write(digit);
}
```

For receiving int:

```
int n = 0; //future result
int decs = 1;
int temp;

while ((temp = BTSerial.read()) != -1) {
    n += temp * decs;
    decs *= 10;
}
```

Comment: `write` can work with multibyte data according to [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialWrite).

Comment: Interesting it's not in linked source code. Maybe different library.

Comment: all methods are in the base class Print and are implemented using pure virtual write(byte) which must be implemented in derived class. and learn how to decompose a multibyte value to bytes before writing an answer on Stack Overflow

Comment: The point is that with this method you will have three byte transmissions to transmit a single byte such as `112` *and* you will have three relatively heavy divide-by-10 and three modulus-10 operations to do so.

Comment: Another issue: `BTSerial.read()`  return `-1` if no byte is available.

Comment: @thebusybee Good point, corrected my code. Rest of my code I leave as it is. It is not meant to be good to go solution, but inspiration - especially since the library offers API for integers.